# We just bought a house and the guest bathroom has an awful smell coming from the toilet, how can we figure this out?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

The guest bathroom has an awful smell coming from the toilet, how can we figure this out? It isn't too bad, but it isn't something we can mask with anything.

Comment: Has the toilet been flushed recently? It could be the p-trap water evaporated away letting sewer gasses come up from the drain. If you flush the toilet, the smell may go away after a few days.

Answer (score 4):

When I bought my home I had a similar problem and I found out that the wax seal at the bottom of the toilet had deteriorated. When I replaced it and cleaned up the goo around the bottom of the toilet then the problem disappeared. But the above answer can also pose the same problem but once it has been eliminated I would also check for the wax seal at the bottom of the toilet.